# Change behavior off the [_url] shortcode in contact form 7

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I get some dynamic data in the URL that I want to send in my mails.

I use the short code [_url] resulting in this when sending the mails: http://www.example.com/dynamic-content

I want to remove my domain name and only send the dynamic data when using [_url].

Anyone know how to make a function for this?

Comment: How did you go with this @Bosse?

Answer (score 0):

You can add a custom form tag using the `wpcf7_form_tag()` function.

Using that, you can then return whatever data - or make whatever changes to that data - that you like.

In your theme's **functions.php**:

```
add_filter("wpcf7_form_tag", "so_37392974_cf7_url");

function so_37392974_cf7_url($form_tag){
  if($form_tag["name"] == "_custom_url"){
    $form_tag["values"][] = $_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"];
  }
  return $form_tag;
}
```

When you then add the `[_custom_url]` tag to your form's e-mail template, it will return something similar to `/dynamic-content`.

I'm not sure exactly what different forms you are planning on that 'dynamic_content' portion to take, but you can use any PHP function (such as str_replace, substr etc.) to massage the value in the function above before returning it.